# React-Native performance with small components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Quick question,

In order to organize my project, I have a few `LinearGradient` components defined similarly to this:

```
export class YellowGradient extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return <LinearGradient id="yellow-gradient" x1="200" y1="0" x2="200" y2="400">
            <Stop offset="0" stopColor="#f4eb42" />
            <Stop offset="1" stopColor="#e0db7d" />
        </LinearGradient>
    }
}
```

This enables me to reuse similar colors across the system on SVG components(ie. I just need to add a `<YellowGradient>` to the definitions of a SVG component when  I want this yellow gradient), however I'm worried that nesting components like this might add too much overhead into the app.

Am I right to be worried, or do small constant components like these get optimized away? Is there a better pattern to follow in order to reuse small components like these?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to know is to test it. If you do however run into any optimization issues, I recommend using `React.PureComponent`. This will increase your application speed and stop those rerenders which slows down the app.